# Form submission in angular 2

Tags: angular, spring-boot

I have successfully implemented Http post request with my rest micro service .

When i make post request using the login form ,if the username password matches with database entry , it gives me back the username password in my console.

And if the username password does not exist, it returns me null.

But i want to redirect to my homepage only after successful login i.e if username and password is correct.

How to check if my console returns me null then i should not redirect ?

### Below shown is my code

### app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from "./header.component";
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';

import { GetService } from './home/get.service';
import { PostService } from './login/post.service';

import { routing } from "./app.routing";
import { RouterModule, Routes} from '@angular/router';


import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

@NgModule({

  declarations: [AppComponent,HeaderComponent,LoginComponent,HomeComponent],

  imports: [RouterModule,BrowserModule, HttpModule , routing ],

  providers: [GetService,PostService],

  bootstrap: [AppComponent]

})

export class AppModule { }
```

### app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html'

})
export class AppComponent {
  title = '';
}
```

### app.component.html

```
<div style="text-align:justify-all;">
  <h1>
    {{title}}
  </h1>

 <div class="container">
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

### app.routing.ts

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from "@angular/router";
import { LoginComponent } from "./login/login.component";
import { HomeComponent } from "./home/home.component";

const APP_ROUTES: Routes = [
{ path: '' , redirectTo: '/homepage', pathMatch: 'full' },
{ path: 'homepage', component: LoginComponent },
{ path: 'homepage/home', component: HomeComponent }
];

export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(APP_ROUTES);
```

### header.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
})
export class HeaderComponent {}
```

### header.component.html

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12"><ul class="nav nav-pills">
<li routerLinkActive="active"><a [routerLink]="['/homepage/home']">
<strong>Home</strong></a></li>
<li><a [routerLink]="['/homepage']"><strong>Logout</strong></a></li>
</ul></div>
</div>
```

### Here is my login component where i have implemented the post request

### login.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { PostService } from './post.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
})


export class LoginComponent {
  data:any;

  constructor(private router:Router ,private MyService: PostService){ }

 checkByCredential(username: string, password: string) 
 {
   this.MyService.checkByCredential(username, password).subscribe(users => console.log(users));

    this.router.navigate(['homepage/home']);
  }
}
```

As shown above in the login.component.ts file i need to check if my console returns me null then i should not redirect else i should redirect to /homepage/home

### login.component.html

```
<div class="container formWidth" style="text-align:center;">
  <h1> eSpace Login</h1><hr>
<br/>
     <h2>Login</h2>
    <form role="form">
      <div ng-control-group="credentials">
        <label for="username">Username</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          #username
          id="username"
          ng-control="username"
          required>
<br/>
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input
          type="password"
          #password
          id="password"
          ng-control="password"
          required>
      </div>
      <button type="button" (click)="checkByCredential(username.value,password.value)">Login</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

### post.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';


@Injectable()
export class PostService {
constructor(private http:Http) { }

 checkByCredential(username: string, password: string) {
 const user = { username: username, password: password };
 return this.http
    .post('http://localhost:8080/checkByCredential', user) 
    .map(result => result.json());
  } }
```

### Here is my home component in which i implemented get request

### home.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { GetService } from './get.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})

export class HomeComponent{
 title :string;
  data:any;


  constructor(private MyService: GetService){
  this.title="Angular Service";

  this.MyService.GetUsers()
 .subscribe(users => {this.data=users });
 }
}
```

### home.component.html

```
<app-header></app-header>
    <hr>
<p> <strong> Welcome to eSpace Home </strong></p>

<!-- <img src="/../../assets/i9.jpeg" class="img-rounded" alt="home" 
height="400" width="1150">-->

    <div style="margin-left:50px; height: 200px; overflow: auto;"> 
        <h4>Angular GET service</h4><hr>
             <table>
                 <tr><td>Username</td>&emsp;&emsp;<td>Password</td></tr>
                 <tr *ngFor= " let item of data">
             <td>{{ item.username }}</td>&emsp;&emsp;<td>{{ item.password }}
 </td>
             </tr>
             </table>
            </div>
```

### get.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';


@Injectable()
export class GetService {
constructor(private http:Http) { }


GetUsers(){
  return this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/checkUsers')
    .map(result => result.json());
           }
 }
```

### Here are the screen shots of my output

when i submit my form with the username and password which is not in my database,even then its redirecting me to homepage and returns null in my console

[image]

[image]

And when the credentials match my database ,even then it redirects to homepage and returns the credentials

[image]

[image]

can anybody please suggest me how to verify and redirect ?

Answer (score 1):

You just have to move your redirection in your subscription to your login service :

```
 checkByCredential(username: string, password: string) 
 {
   this.MyService.checkByCredential(username, password)
   .subscribe(users => {
     console.log(users);
     if (!users) {
       return // <= do nothing if the server's response is null
     } else {
       this.router.navigate(['homepage/home']); // <= redirect if it is ok
       }
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: i updated my code but i am getting this error in my terminal, and i am unable to resolve..please guide me

Comment: ERROR in C:/Angular/homepage/src/app/login/login.component.ts (20,24): ';' expected.
ERROR in C:/Angular/homepage/src/app/login/login.component.ts (29,1): Declaration or statement expected.
ERROR in C:/Angular/homepage/src/app/login/login.component.ts (21,11): Cannot find name 'users'.

Answer (score 1):

In your **login.component.ts**, you have your `router.navigate` outside of the subscribe.

An observable is asynchronous, so `router.navigate` will be trigger indepedently of chechByCredential.

If you want trigger the navigation when you have the API's answer, you could put your code into the subscribe:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { PostService } from './post.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
})


export class LoginComponent {
  data:any;

  constructor(private router:Router ,private MyService: PostService){ }

 checkByCredential(username: string, password: string) 
 {
   this.MyService.checkByCredential(username, password)
      .subscribe(users => {
           if(users)
              this.router.navigate(['homepage/home']);
           else
              console.log(users) //or do somethings else
      });        
  }
}
```

Comment: thankyou so much for your response.. i will try this out and will be back in a moment

Comment: iam getting this error in my terminal and i am unable to resolve .ERROR in C:/Angular/homepage/src/app/login/login.component.ts (24,7): Declaration or statement expected.

Comment: I forget a bracket after the else maybe is that if you copy past my code

Comment: thanks for response and sharing this valuable information

Comment: one more query please

Comment: in my home component i implemented get request which gives the database entries.. i want to add loadusers button in home page... and when i click loadusers in my home page it should list all the entries

Comment: i tried with adding a "loaduser"  button in home.component.html and invoking loaduser() in my home.component.ts file and placed the get request functionality within that function

Comment: but i am unable to get proper output

Comment: @Heena what mean a proper output?

Comment: just i want to add a button loadusers which on click list the credentials present in the database as you can see in my homepage screen shot

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160614/discussion-between-mickaelw-and-heena).

Comment: ..hello again.. i got a query
as in my login form i didn't apply any validators .. i am now trying to modify my form as reactive form ,but iam unable to get a post with the updated form .can you please guide me how to apply validators to my login form?